# Classic Asp - ADO subroutine not calling correctly

Tags: sql, database, asp-classic, ado

I have a subroutine in my asp file, I am trying to add to a database table.
When I remove the subroutine wrapper from the logic, it works. (but of course, submits automatically before any user interaction).

I have tested this backwards and forwards and I cannot for the life of me see why this is happening.  I've added logic to prevent the data being able to be submitted if the fields values are empty, or the button hasn't been pressed.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.. must admit this one is driving me bonkers, as I'm copying it from another routine I wrote on another page that is working perfectly.

Thanks.

````
<%  Dim objConn, connStr, strSql
    Dim iCommandID
    Dim strUserName, strEmailAddress, strPassword1, bSubmit
    iCommandID = Request.Form("cmdID")
    strUserName = CStr(Request.Form("username")) 
    strEmailAddress = CStr(Request.Form("emailAddress"))
    strPassword1 = CStr(Request.form("password1"))
    bSubmit = Request.Form("btnSubmit")
   
  
   If Request.Form("cmdID").Count > 0 Then 
        iCommandID = CLng(Request.Form("cmdID"))
    ElseIf Request.QueryString("cmdID").Count > 0 Then 
        iCommandID = Clng(Request.QueryString("cmdID"))
Else 
  iCommandID = 0
End If 
response.write(iCommandID)

SELECT CASE iCommandID
    CASE 1
        addUser
END SELECT 
        


Sub addUser
    If bSubmit <> "" Then 
        If strUserName <> "" AND strEmailAddress <> "" AND strPassword1 <> "" Then 
            connStr = Application("DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING")
            Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
                objConn.Open(connStr)
                strSql = "INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_Users (userName, userEmailAdd, userPassHash) VALUES (" + "'" + strUserName + "'," + "'" + strEmailAddress + "'," + "'" + strPassword1 + "'" + ")"
                objConn.Execute strSql, , adCmdText
                objConn.Close
            Set objConn = Nothing
        End If 
    End If 
End Sub
%> ```
````

Comment: Its been awhile since I did asp but I think the culprit is ...If bSubmit <> "" Then... Can you change that to a click event?

Comment: Hiya CJ.  I can, but in this case I'm better not to.  I've got a handler on the form submit button to run some sanitisation.  
The process is click button > run that sanisiation > update the command id > check command id > run subroutine if it's 1.   

It's honestly going to come back to something very simple to do with ordering, I think, but I just can't see it.

Comment: hmm, but you are grabbing values from I assume inputs on a form,  which makes sense, but I have never seen grabbing the value of a button like that. Are you adding a hidden value in the button element? Also, I can't remember if VB is case sensitive but your password request small f instead of capitalized F

Comment: Yep, exactly right, hidden input on the form, that's being updated on submission.  
I think I've narrowed it down, but unsure where to fix it at the moment:  
Before the select case, i hardcoded the commandid to 1, and it worked, which is telling m e it's not being updated correctly from the form.. 
Perhaps if I create a separate function and have it as a callback for the sanitisation.

Comment: Okay, I see, I would make sure the ... If bSubmit <> "" Then ... logic is working, then add the 3 input checks one by one to make sure one is not breaking. I am assuming iCommandID is in fact 1. I would also check your form and make sure the inputs are named correctly, one small error and one of them could come back as ""

Comment: Good advice, thanks.  I'll go have a look over those points now to be sure.  
Very strange, as it all definitely works other than that id updating :shrug:

Comment: Can you [edit] and add the html form and the validating script part too?

Comment: Apologies for my delay.  This is part of a personal project, and have been working for the last couple of days.  I will edit and add those sections tonight.  Thanks.